# Matlab guide help, changing the string for a radiobutton from the workspace

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

When using the guide function on MatLab, how do you change the string (name) of a radiobutton from the workspace, without requiring some sort of user input first? 
For example,

```
function radiobutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% hObject    handle to radiobutton1 (see GCBO) 
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB 
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA) 
handles = guidata(hObject); 
buttonname = 'A' 
set(handles.radiobutton1,'string', buttonname); 
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

This changes the name of the radiobutton once it has been selected, but not before. How would I change the string from the start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CreateFcn` callback? Add a function called `radiobutton1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)` and put your code inside that function. It is executed when the object is created. This should work if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I have that function at the top already. The code is just not executed until I click the radiobutton when I run it. I was trying to find a way for it to be executed from the start. I.e. When I run the GUI the radiobutton displays 'radiobutton' for the string and when I select it it displays 'A' I want it to display A from the start.

Answer (score 0):

When working with GUIDE function called "*Fun*", there are three ways in order to change "initial" attributes of an object such as a radio button with the tag "*radiobutton1*".
The following functions run before it is displayed.

1. ***Fun*_OpeningFcn**
2. ***Fun*_OutputFcn**
3. ***radiobutton1*_CreateFcn**

Therefore, you can simply add the new attributes in any part of the above functions. For example, by adding the following modifier to "Fun_OpeningFcn", the string value changes from the beginning:

set(handles.*radiobutton1*,'String','*New_String*')

On the other hand, if you want an attribute to get changed after a certain callback action, this modifier should be added to the related callback. When you add this part in the radio button callback function, it means, if the user selected this radio button the name of the radio button will be changed, Which is certainly not your purpose.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!